# Showing values of multiple columns in database via android

Tags: android

I have an app that should send a the phone number and retrieve a value from the  database, now I change the query and my code should retrieve values of multiple columns, So where changes should be in my code.

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String>
{
    HttpResponse response;

    String url = "http://192.168.1.97:89/Derdeery/bankOsman.php";

    private AsyncCallback asyncCallback;

    public JSONTransmitter(Context context) {
        // attach the callback to any context
        asyncCallback = (AsyncCallback) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        asyncCallback.onResponse(result);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... data)
    {
        JSONObject json = data[0];

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


        String resFromServer = "";

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json=" + json.toString());

            post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            post.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(post);
            resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.i("Response from server", resFromServer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resFromServer;
    }

    public static interface AsyncCallback {
        void onResponse(String res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to consider:

- First, in your php code (server-side), query your data perhaps separately. So for instance, you can get those that match column A and then query for those that match column B.
- Generate Json for each (A and B accordingly)
- Then create a single JSON object that contains the two sets of data like this:

  {
    "DataFromColumnA" : {},
    "DataFromColumnB" : {}
  }
- Once you have made your HTTP request in your android code, you can get the specific data by getting "DataFromColumnA" json Object and B respectively.

I hope this helps you get your problem solved!

Comment: Am sorry I changed my question  what to do if there are unknown number of column to retrieve their values

Comment: I think the best way would be to send your get requests with whatever column names you need to query in your database - that way, you can use them to easily map the columns in the remote server